# Open a .pdf file with Rails outside the public folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, file-io, ruby-on-rails-3.2, public

I'm new to the programming world and I'm working with Rails to create my first project.  I have a library of .pdf files saved on a separate shared network server.  I would like to make links to some of these files so that when I click the link, the pdf opens in the browser.

I understand that by using:

```
<a href="/filename.pdf">Click Me</a>
```

I can open a file in the /public folder in my rails project, but I'm looking to open a file on a completely different harddrive.  I've tried

```
`href="//drivename/folder/nextfolder/filename.pdf" `
```

but the browser gives me a 404 error saying file not found.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Better use a controller action to serve the file:

say you have pdfs controller,

#### in view:

```
<a href="pdfs/serve/filename">Click Me</a>
```

#### in controller

```
def serve
  path = "/drivename/folder/nextfolder/#{params[:filename]}"

  send_file( path,
  :disposition => 'inline',
  :type => 'application/pdf',
  :x_sendfile => true )
end
```

Comment: how to use send_file to open 'files' in new tab?